# Android mirror vector drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, vector, drawable

I use a material icon (ic_play_arrow_black_24dp), imported it with the vector studio.

Now I want the arrow to point in the other direction as well, without creating a second vector. Is this possible in xml and how?

I use the drawable in two Floating Action Button, one for next the other for previous.

**Edit**
here is the fab button's XML. I tried already rotation and scale, but it didn´t work

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/next_prev_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/next"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="left" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - flip image in xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338447/android-flip-image-in-xml)

Comment: I saw this already but it didn´t work for my fab. I added the xml of the fab, maybe something is wrong in there?

Comment: use `android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable`

Comment: Related: mirroring arbitrary Drawable programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502102/3050249

Comment: Short Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783080/1164529

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For those who Use `ImageView` or `TextView` or `EditText` Scale works perfectly. Use

```
android:scaleX="-1" //To flip horizontally or
android:scaleY="-1" //To flip vertically
```

OR Try

```
android:rotationX="180" // for horizontal
android:rotationY="180" // for vertical
```

OR Simply `rotation="180"` for vertical

```
android:rotation="180" // for vertical
```

**Edit:** Additional
If you want to flip/mirror icons/drawable when changing language RTL/LTR ("Right To Left"/"Left To Right"), there is a nice way of doing so in android vector drawable just check the ckeckbox **Enable auto mirroring for RTL layout**.

> => Right Click on drawable folder => New => Vector Asset => Select drawable => check the Checkbox

.

Answer (score 16):

There is an alternate way to mirror a drawable. You can modify the xml file to add a `<group>` tag to mirror the image (vertically here)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="30"
    android:viewportHeight="30">
    
    <group
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:translateX="30"> <!-- viewportWidth here-->
        
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFF"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M14.667 4V0L9.333 5.333l5.334 5.334v-4c4.413 0 8 3.586 8 8a7.827 7.827 0 0 1-.934 3.733l1.947 1.947a10.574 10.574 0 0 0 1.653-5.68C25.333 8.773 20.56 4 14.667 4zm0 18.667c-4.414 0-8-3.587-8-8 0-1.347.333-2.627.933-3.734L5.653 8.987A10.574 10.574 0 0 0 4 14.667c0 5.893 4.773 10.666 10.667 10.666v4L20 24l-5.333-5.333v4z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. My icon was originally rtl.

Answer (score 15):

I am using `AndroidStudio 3.0.1` in `Windows 10`.

well, there is no need to create another vector image, you can do it with one single vector image just make sure you do the following step while importing the `vector image`

So,
do usual step to create `vector_drawable`,

in case some one don't know,

than here it is..

**1.)** Right Click on your `package` of your app

**2.)** Than navigate to `New => Vector Asset`

**3.)** Than choose your desired icon, in @reebov case it will be `ic_arrow_back_black_24dp`

**4.)** You will find `Checkbox` with the **Option** `Enable auto mirroring for RTL layout`.

**EDIT**

> You can also Set `android:autoMirrored="true"` in your XML vector file

***see below image for more info***

[image: see image for more info]

and your are done. :)

Answer (score 10):

Set `android:autoMirrored="true"` in your XML vector file,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the share image vectore xml file
**share.xml :**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M10,9V5l-7,7 7,7v-4.1c5,0 8.5,1.6 11,5.1 -1,-5 -4,-10 -11,-11z"/>
</vector>
```

**Here is the image in xml layout file :**

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="32dp"
      android:layout_height="32dp"
      android:src="@drawable/share"
      android:scaleX="-1"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

This line is used to mirror a vector image :

```
   android:scaleX="-1"
```