# Fliping Drawable Image in Vector Drawable

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have found this vector drawable resource [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/). What I would like to do is flip it so the **X** is on the other side.

I managed to do this in the layout, like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338447/android-flip-image-in-xml) by adding:
`android:scaleX="-1"`
to my ImageView and it works.

Now I would like to change it directly in the Vector Drawable, but when I try the code below it is invisible.

account_remove.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:scaleX="-1" >

        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:pathData="M15,14C17.67,14 23,15.33 23,18V20H7V18C7,15.33 12.33,14 15,14M15,12A4,4 0 0,1 11,8A4,4 0 0,1 15,4A4,4 0 0,1 19,8A4,4 0 0,1 15,12M5,9.59L7.12,7.46L8.54,8.88L6.41,11L8.54,13.12L7.12,14.54L5,12.41L2.88,14.54L1.46,13.12L3.59,11L1.46,8.88L2.88,7.46L5,9.59Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

And when I add:

```
android:pivotX="10.0"
android:pivotY="10.0"
```

to `rotationGroup` it is tilted to the right.

***What values should I add to my `rotationGroup` to make it work correctly?***

Comment: is preview does not show image or device? because above link, one comment says it not showing in preview but working in device

Comment: or try to use android:rotationX="180" instead of android:scaleX="-1"

Comment: Or you can find some svg image edditing tool, and edit the image as you like it.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel It does not show on the device. I tried to use `android:rotationX="180"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You were almost doing it, just with the wrong pivot point.

It needs to flip around the centre of the image, so looking at the viewport the full width is 24, so the pivot point needs to be at 12.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:scaleX="-1" >

        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:pathData="M15,14C17.67,14 23,15.33 23,18V20H7V18C7,15.33 12.33,14 15,14M15,12A4,4 0 0,1 11,8A4,4 0 0,1 15,4A4,4 0 0,1 19,8A4,4 0 0,1 15,12M5,9.59L7.12,7.46L8.54,8.88L6.41,11L8.54,13.12L7.12,14.54L5,12.41L2.88,14.54L1.46,13.12L3.59,11L1.46,8.88L2.88,7.46L5,9.59Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: Information: `android:pivotX="Z"` the static Z has to be half of the value of your `android:viewportWidth`