# How to get a Drawable that's a mirrored version of a different Drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, image-rotation

### Background

I know it's possible to create a rotated version of a Drawable (or Bitmap), as such (written about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376008/878126)) :

```
@JvmStatic
fun getRotateDrawable(d: Drawable, angle: Int): Drawable {
    if (angle % 360 == 0)
       return d
    return object : LayerDrawable(arrayOf(d)) {
        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.save()
            canvas.rotate(angle.toFloat(), (d.bounds.width() / 2).toFloat(), (d.bounds.height() / 2).toFloat())
            super.draw(canvas)
            canvas.restore()
        }
    }
}
```

### The problem

I wanted to have `autoMirrored` being set to some drawable (VectorDrawable in my case), which would flip (mirror so that left is right, and right is left, but not affect top and bottom) it in case the locale of the device is RTL.

As an example (and it's only an example!), if you take a drawable that shows a left-arrow, after flipping it will be a right-arrow.

Sadly, this is available only from API 19.

That's why I decided to make a new Drawable out of it, to be a flipped version of the original one

### What I've tried

I've found a nice article of doing the same thing to a View, [**here**](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/image-flipping-mirroring-in-imageview.html), using a Matrix. So I've tried this:

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun getMirroredDrawable(d: Drawable): Drawable {
        return object : LayerDrawable(arrayOf(d)) {
            override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
                canvas.save()
                val matrix = Matrix()
                // use this for the other flipping: matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f)
                matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
                canvas.matrix = matrix
                super.draw(canvas)
                canvas.restore()
            }
        }
    }
```

Sadly, for some reason, this made the drawable not being shown at all. Maybe it does work, yet tries to get shown out of its bounds of whatever View that's showing it.

### The question

How can I make a flipped version of a given Drawable, similar to what I did for rotating a Drawable?

---

Solution:

Based on the answer suggested below ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502102/878126)), here's a nice way to do it:

```
fun Drawable.getMirroredDrawable(): Drawable {
    return object : LayerDrawable(arrayOf(this)) {
        val drawingRect = Rect()
        val matrix = Matrix()
        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
            matrix.reset()
            matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f, canvas.width / 2.0f, canvas.height / 2.0f)
            canvas.matrix = matrix
            drawingRect.left = (canvas.width - intrinsicWidth) / 2
            drawingRect.top = (canvas.height - intrinsicHeight) / 2
            drawingRect.right = drawingRect.left + intrinsicWidth
            drawingRect.bottom = drawingRect.top + intrinsicHeight
            if (bounds != drawingRect)
                bounds = drawingRect
            super.draw(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I have tested this and it will not work for scaled drawables, like vector drawables

Comment: @A.Steenbergen Actually, this works perfectly fine for VectorDrawable. It's what I tried to test. If you wish, put a link to a minimal project (here : https://uploadfiles.io/ ) , and I will show you how to fix it.

Comment: It did not resize to fill the imageView I was using it in (the non-mirrored version did). I had to change the drawingRect to left=0, top=0, right=canvas.width(), bottom=canvas.height()

Comment: @A.Steenbergen Please show an example in a project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the center for the flip operation.

```
matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
```

Here is a custom `Drawable` class that you can use to mirror drawables:

```
public class MirroredDrawable extends Drawable {
    final Drawable mDrawable;
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    MirroredDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);

        Rect drawingRect = new Rect();
        drawingRect.left = (canvas.getWidth() - mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2;
        drawingRect.top = (canvas.getHeight() - mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        drawingRect.right = drawingRect.left + mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        drawingRect.bottom = drawingRect.top + mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDrawable.setBounds(drawingRect);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    // Other methods required to extend Drawable but aren't used here.

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) { }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) { }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() { return PixelFormat.OPAQUE; }
}
```

Here is how it can be applied:

```
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(new MirroredDrawable(drawable));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be shown. I use the output drawable for `setHomeAsUpIndicator` . Can you please try it? Or, maybe show full code, because what I did is use this on the problematic code I've made.

Comment: This works, but also the code I've written, if I had changed it to what you have. Just a small suggestion for improvement (which for some reason I didn't do): create the matrix once, as a field, and call `reset()` on it in the `draw` method, to reduce re-creation of it, over and over.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Updated. Also added code to make sure the drawable is the right size. It was too big for the "as up indicator."

Comment: What should be implemented for the `Other methods required to extend Drawable` part? And how? Can you please fill it too ? Also, I've updated your code a bit.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Added them to answer. They are just stubs in this implementation.

Comment: ok thank you for this. I guess that my solution, after I change it to have the `draw` implementation of yours, will also be ok, right? I've tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Should be OK.

Comment: OK granted bounty. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `android:scaleX="-1"` in the view's xml to show the drawable's mirror image. To make it work automatically depending on the layout's direction, you could use an integer resource value:

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleX="@integer/rtl_flip_factor"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>
```

To finish it off, you'd need a plain `values/integers.xml` for the default (LTR) case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="rtl_flip_factor">1</integer>
</resources>
```

and another `values-ldrtl/integers.xml` for the RTL case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="rtl_flip_factor">-1</integer>
</resources>
```

Comment: I need it in code, programmatically. I use it for `setHomeAsUpIndicator`, in case the device is in RTL locale, because `autoMirrored` is only supported on new Android APIs. There is no ImageView in my case. Just a Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:autoMirrored="true"` in your XML vector file,

Comment: The question is how to do it programmatically, for any drawable. Not just VectorDrawable..

Comment: okay good , may help someone searching for mirroring xml vectorDrawable

Comment: No, because I already mentioned that I know of "autoMirrored" and wanted to apply it to Drawable.